# Where to get a list of ALL facebook stream posts types?

Tags: facebook-fql

I can find posts types here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/ (in the description of field "type"), but it's definitely not full list. Because the query

```
SELECT post_id, type, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0
```

returns also types 65, 161. I believe there're also some other post types, which are not documented here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/.

Where can I get the full list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that it's a known issue on Facebook. On this page with bug description you can find more error codes:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/154511994682996/

from: Osborne Lopes · Assistant Manager at National Securities Depository Ltd. (NSDL)

The codes are:

11 - Group created.
12 - Event created.
46 - Status update.
56 - Post on Timeline from another user.
60 - changed profile picture.
65 - Tagged photo.
66 - Note created.
80 - Link posted ( shared Photo/Link).
128 - Video posted.
161 - Likes*.
245 - Likes a photo/Link*.
247 - Photos posted.
237 - App/Games story.
257 - Comment created.
272 - App story.
283 - Likes a Link*.
285 - Checkin to a place.
295 - Post to Timeline of a friend from other friend.
308 - Post in Group.
347 - Likes a Link*.
373 - updated cover photo.

Comment: Thanks! Though, it's not the official full list yet, as I understand :(