# Is it possible to get User feed with FQL?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-wall

Is it possible to use FQL to get user's feed?
To get the same like graph.facebook.com/user/feed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request mentioned in cpilko's answer will get you the current user's Newsfeed (i.e. the equivalent of Graph API's /me/home). Therefore I don't think that answer should have been accepted.

As for the current user's Timeline (i.e. the equivalent of Graph API's /me/feed): There is no easy way to get this with only one request because the Timeline contains different pieces of information:

- It contains status updates by the current user.
- It contains posts by other users that are targeted to the current user.
- It does NOT contain posts by the current user targeted to other users, events, etc.
- It does NOT contain stories by the current user that have neither a message text nor an attached photo, link, or place.*

*: I'm not 100% sure on the last one because information on this is sketchy at best. There are different post types (a complete list of which I haven't seen yet), and there seems to be some kind of logic which types are shown on the Timeline and which are not. As I said, documentation is sketchy and it seems like Facebook doesn't want you to get exactly the same data as they do.

Now to answer your question:
If you're planning to offer a user's Timeline as part of your app experience, you should probably aim at a best-guess approach.

Here is an example that I find comes pretty close (except that it doesn't get you posts of friends on your Timeline, but as I said: best-guess):

> ```
> SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, description, message, attachment, type, permalink
> FROM stream 
> WHERE source_id = me()
> AND is_hidden != "true"
> AND (type = 46 OR type = 60 OR type = 65 OR type = 80 OR type = 128 OR type = 247 OR type = 285 OR type = 373)
> LIMIT 100
> ```

By the way, this is the most complete list of post types I have found so far:
[Where to get a list of ALL facebook stream posts types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243641/where-to-get-a-list-of-all-facebook-stream-posts-types)

Hope this helps, even though the answer admittedly isn't that encouraging. :)

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent table in FQL is [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/). This query gets you the active user's news feed.

SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking friend's wall. But I guess it comes when you set source_id = friend_id

Comment: You'd change the above query to `uid = FRIEND_ID` to get a friend's newsfeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do on this way

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id='SOURCE_ID' AND created_time<1225705644 LIMIT 150
```

set SOURCE_ID with your friend's id.

Comment: No, this way it will only give posts which are posted by your friend, not his view of "News Feed"

Comment: @BlackDivine The question mentioned "To get the same like graph.facebook.com/user/feed", not "To get the same like graph.facebook.com/user/home" as you're talking about, so he's asking for timeline feed, not newsfeed. Moreover, the comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992905/is-it-possible-to-get-user-feed-with-fql/16102909?noredirect=1#comment17741954_13014071 indicated this: "but I'm asking friend's wall."

Comment: @BlackDivine i'm not understand why the answer is accepted because you would get error "(#606) uid in the where clause must be the session user" if you try to replace 'uid=me()' to 'uid=FRIEND_ID'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try in following way: see if it helps.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, type, permalink, message, created_time, likes, comment_info FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND app_id = AppID
```

If you pass app id then it will return your friends feed posted from that app only.